Need to insert text in a VS Code document using tabs
I'm writing a VS Code extension in TypeScript and need to insert indented text in a TextDocument using tabs or spaces as indicated by the TextEditorOptions. I can handle the resolution of tabs manually but I'm wondering if there is an idiomatic way using the VSCode API.
Indent position is taken from TextEditor.selection.end.character. If tabs are used, this will not be the actual insert location without adjusting for TextEditorOptions.tabSize.
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
        int countdown = -1;

        Text to be inserted here.
^^^^^^^^Need to indent with tabs.

        static const char invalid[] = "Invalid countdown %s, try again...\n";
        if (argc > 1) {
                char* end;
                countdown = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);

Is there some feature in the API that will handle insertion of tabs/spaces automatically or do I need to do it manually?

Here's the solution I'm using. If anyone has a better one, please share.
Given editor as the TextEditor object, here is a solution that works:
      const doc        = editor.document;
      const selection  = editor.selection;
      const start      = selection.start;
      const end        = selection.end;
      const tabSize    = editor.options.tabSize as number;
      const useTabs    = !editor.options.insertSpaces;

      const indentPos  = 
        doc.lineAt(end.line).text.substring(0, end.character)
        .replace(/\t/g, " ".repeat(tabSize))
        .length;

      const tabCount   = useTabs ? Math.trunc(indentPos/tabSize) : 0;
      const spcCount   = useTabs ? indentPos%tabSize             : indentPos;
      const indentText = "\t".repeat(tabCount)+" ".repeat(spcCount);




Value
Description




useTabs
true when indenting with tabs. false when indenting with spaces.


indentPos
Actual indent position adjusted for TextEditorOptions.tabSize.


indentText
String to prepend to inserted lines. Includes tab characters when indenting with tabs.



